# Editing a textview via another class

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to create a communication system between my server computer and my android smartphone. I am, finally, getting good results of the work. However, I have a problem with the android views. Specifically, I am trying to use the method ".setText()" of a textview from a class which has no extention. I passed my textview object to that class but the method "textview.setText()" works without any failure and having no effect on the UI. Let me right down the code and I guess you will understand more clearly and have a chance to try the code.

```
public class NetworkingActivity extends Activity {

    public static String message;
    public static EditText editext;
    public static TextView textview;
    private Connector connector;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }


    public void buttonClicked(View v){
        editext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        message = editext.getText().toString();

        connector = new Connector(NetworkingActivity.this);
        connector.start();

    }

    public void yenile(String respond){
        textview.setText(respond);
        editext.setText("");

    }

    public void yenileClicked(View v){
        textview.setText(Connector.respond);
        editext.setText("");

    }

    public static class Connector extends Thread{
        private static final int PORT = 3588;
        private static final String IpAddress = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"; // of course X's have a int value
        public static String respond;
        private NetworkingActivity activity;

        public Connector(NetworkingActivity activity){
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public void run() {

            try {

                Socket socket = new Socket(IpAddress, PORT);

                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());

                writer.println(NetworkingActivity.message);
                respond = scanner.nextLine();


                activity.yenile(respond);

                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Finally, I should tell you one more thing. The method yenileClicked() is assigned by a code in the xml file which is " android:onClick="yenileClicked" " via a button. The problem is the disability of the other class to proceed the almost same method yenile();

Comment: The issue is you can't edit the View from a separate thread. use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)
So it would look like `activity.runOnUIThread(new Runnable{ public void run() { activity.yenile(respond); } });` 
to make your current code work. I would consider creating an interface callback instead of passing the whole activity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use any of the following:

1. use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).
2. use [Handler.post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29)
3. probably easiest in your case: use [textview.post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29)
4. not quite fit here , but could be nice too for similar tasks : use [asycnTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) .